# Workaround for Ctrl-Space in Konsole

Tags: terminal, keyboard-layout, konsole

After upgrading from Kubuntu 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS, Konsole 15.12.3 with Qt 5.5.1 under the KDE framework 5.18.0 no longer [recognizes](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=341157) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. Are there any workarounds to get it working, apart from using the somewhat awkward <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>@</kbd> (which also doesn't seem to work)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably no workaround, judging by the fix applied in  *[Bug 341157 - Konsole5 doesn't send Ctrl+Space anymore](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=341157)* .

At the end of the report, someone stated that it did not work for them.  I just verified that the version in Debian/testing works for me.  See screenshot:

[image]